# For..of loops confusion

Tags: arrays, for-loop, logic, increment, semantics

So I've been writing 'for' loops only with the (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) set up until now. This is visually something you can break down and understand so its been logical for me. Now I'm being taught the for..of loop and it's not as easy to directly see whats going on. I understand its just a simpler way to write it in relation to arrays - but I'm wondering if they have designed it to operate as a function with the keywords 'for' 'const' and 'of' or if someone might be able to help me understand how this code is actually operating?

I tried to formulate the question to someone but it seems from their response maybe this is just going to be one of those things you just DO without actually seeing the logic of how its working in itself. As far as I can tell it operates more like a function with parameters?

```
const clay = [ "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay" ]
const toFireInKiln = []

for (const i of clay) {
   const mug = `${i} coffee mug`
   toFireInKiln.push(mug)
}



console.log(toFireInKiln)
```

I can use it as it's meant to be used but I am not understanding the functionality as it runs.

Comment: It's just taking an element of the array, one at a time, in a loop. Isn't that logical enough?

Comment: I can use it and have been its just most stuff I had encountered had the logic written out for you to see but I'm over it its fine! I was just curious if its a method or something special since it doesn't make sense visually like the other loop I had learned initially. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "make sense visually"?

Comment: You can actually break down the logic of the for (let i = 0, i < n; i++) loop and see how its iterating through each one. It shows the logic. Instead of being for(this of this), you can actually break it down mentally and watch the flow of iteration as you consider that the integer(i) is changing with each iteration, you can see that the integer increments and so it increments your position through the array since the array is then given the index of the integer. It's just the way I learned it, and everything else I had learned til that point had that kind of visual logic!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this C# example helps, but here are two versions of the code - one using `foreach` and the other using the underlying method calls that make it work.

```
IEnumerable<string> letters = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

foreach (string letter in letters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
}

using (var e = letters.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
    }
}
```

The IL (bytecode) that gets generated is pretty much identical for both blocks of code.